# tobytes() not preserving dimension information of numpy array generated from PyTorch tensor

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, serialization, pytorch

Using a simple feature extractor in PyTorch I generate a (1,512) features vector from a (200,200,3) RGB image. I want to serialise these features using ndarray.tobytes() for storage purposes and subsequently reload and reconstruct the original feature vector at a later time. When I do the serialisation (ndarray.tobytes) the resultant byte string is of length 2048, and when I reconstruct the feature numpy array using np.frombuffer() the size is also (2048). This behaviour doesn't happen if I use np.tobytes() directly on a numpy array of (1, 512). Why are the dimensions of the array not preserved using numpy serialisation?

```
def get_singlescale_features(self,image):

    transform=T.Compose([T.ToTensor()])
    image=Image.fromarray(image)
    image=transform(image)
    image=torch.unsqueeze(image,0)
    feature=self.model(image)
    feature=torch.squeeze(feature)
    return feature

image=Image.open(img_path) #shape -> (200,200,3)
feature=extractor.get_singlescale_features(image)
feature=feature.detach().numpy()
feature=np.expand_dims(feature,0)
print(features.shape) #shape -> (1,512)
f_bytes=features.tobytes() #shape -> (2048)
feature=np.frombuffer(f_bytes)
print(feature.shape) #shape -> (2048)
```

Comment: Check the `dtype`.  `tobytes/frombuffer` does not 'store' any shape (or dtype) informantion, just the data as bytes.  If you save one dtype, and load another (without specifying the `frombuffer(..., dtype)`, the resulting array may have a different dtype and shape.  2048 is 4x 512.

Comment: @hpaulj this indeed resolved the problem. I needed to make sure that the dtype in np.frombuffer(..., dtype) used to load is the same as the dtype of the array converted and saved with tobytes.

Answer (score 0):

@hpauli has provided the correct answer in his comment above. We need to save using array.tobytes() and load with np.frombuffer(..., dtype) with the same data type (in this case float) otherwise the shape may end up different.

```
def get_singlescale_features(self,image):

    transform=T.Compose([T.ToTensor()])
    image=Image.fromarray(image)
    image=transform(image)
    image=torch.unsqueeze(image,0)
    feature=self.model(image)
    feature=torch.squeeze(feature)
    return feature

image=Image.open(img_path) #shape -> (200,200,3)
feature=extractor.get_singlescale_features(image)
feature=feature.detach().numpy()
feature=np.expand_dims(feature,0)
print(features.shape) #shape -> (1,512)
f_bytes=features.tobytes() #shape -> (2048)
feature=np.frombuffer(f_bytes, dtype=np.float32)
print(feature.shape) #shape -> (1,512)
```